# After upgrade to 16.04 my system reboots continually

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, reboot

Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04, without problems.

But after this operation, every time I walk away, instead of hanging up the PC reboots. The configuration is correct, the temperature of the CPU is normal, and after reboot there aren't any errors showing up.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

only format `Ubuntu` resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing all options to **Do nothing** in the power management settings.

Maybe it's the **Suspend when inactive** function causing this issue.

Comment: Not resolve the problem..